# How to link multiple plots with vega-lite only on horizontal axis?

Tags: vega-lite

I have tested this:
https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVJOmNlADWESlAjEQAXyXEocqGrQBtUJm1JZEAGZs2ggeoP40gphw2vqqmAwIlBAAnghMbIIAvNkA5ACSAEIAsjn2ALpKyNpm+sKycIogcLLOyjSyZGigAB5dIOFwgsqxag1KmMk4DehRCDhBSHoOIMl9A0P6ONo0UGMgE1P6AI4Mvph0ajSk9ssQg3BQ53J92uTs8pr7k9Mg7VHaxEWjSY7WG6GgizgEBuDi8Pj8gWCoX6EX+I3iiRSaQy2UyOQA4gB5Qn40p2CogKo1dB1PbNVrtTqfXqfdZggxRRoHH6zeY+JZKVasmiDdlbHZ7bnHU6yc7qc7XOy3e6Pd4vN7PT5S9B-aKAvRKEGydkQwRQmEU14yQTXT6m6Y9fQQGBIV7DJV2IA

But without success since the vertical axis is also linked.
Is there also a way to limit wheel zoom to one axis only ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can limit the scale binding to a single axis by specifying the `"encodings"` property of the selection. For example, this binds the selection only to the x-axis ([view in vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVJOmNlADWESlAjEQAXyXEocqGrQBtUJm1JZEAGZs2ggeoP40gphw2vqqmAwIlBAAnghMbIIAvNkA5ACSAEIAsjn2ALpKyNpm+sKycIogcLLOyjSyZGigAB5dIOFwgsqxag1KmMk4DehRCDhBSHoOIMl9A0P6ONo0UGMgE1P6AI4Mvph0ajSk9ssQg3BQ53J92uTs8pr7k9Mg7VHaxEWjSY7WG6GgizgEEazVa7TI0NQ7hAvTKdnRCi8Pj8gWCoX6EX+I3iiRSaQy2UyOQA4gB5WnU0p2CogKo1dB1PawthtDp9XqfdZggxRRoHH6zeY+JZKVaCmiDYVbHZ7cXHU6yc7qc7XDEgO6CB5PD6gV60Z6fNXoP7RQF6JQg2TCiGG6FKbm8hEeFEgNHolmvGSCa6fF3THr6CAwJCvYay-SguBTJ3NTA3OxAA)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.symbol==='IBM'"}],
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
      },
      "selection": {
        "region": {"type": "interval", "bind": "scales", "encodings": ["x"]}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.symbol==='GOOG'"}],
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
      },
      "selection": {
        "region": {"type": "interval", "bind": "scales", "encodings": ["x"]}
      }
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {"scale": {"x": "shared", "y": "independent"}}
}
```

[image]

If you want independent y scale binding in each chart, with a shared x-binding, you can do this by adding a new independent bound selection in each chart ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVJOmNlADWESlAjEQAXyXEocqGrQBtUJm1JZEAGZs2ggeoP40gphw2vqqmAwIlBAAnghMbIIAvNkA5ACSAEIAsjn2ALpKyNpm+sKycIogcLLOyjSyZGigAB5dIOFwgsqxag1KmMk4DehRCDhBSHoOIMl9A0P6ONo0UGMgE1P6AI4Mvph0ajSk9ssQg3BQ53J9yQD60NoZgq8AjH0H0xA7Si2mIi0aTHaw3Q0EWcAgjWarXaZARqHcKxAZWW3XeUE+gj0mn2k0BwOiYL0SkhsmhIFhgnhiJabDaHTRGN62LsDi8Pj8gWCoX6ERBI3iiRSaQy2UyOQA4gB5RXy0p2CogKo1dB1PZI1kovq9YnrOlxPYA-SzeY+JZKVYmmiDOlbHYW0nHU6yc7qc7XHlKO6Mx7seTEt4fL6vABM-w96HJoPB1Kh+gZTKU+rZqI8mOxSlxkcJccOCe9FOTIBpdPTCMzLOzHJAXJ56qU2nhGWuxPTRrTMCQHeG9v0ULgU1pzUwNzsQA)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.symbol==='IBM'"}],
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
      },
      "selection": {
        "y_scroll_1": {"type": "interval", "bind": "scales", "encodings": ["y"]},
        "x_scroll": {"type": "interval", "bind": "scales", "encodings": ["x"]}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.symbol==='GOOG'"}],
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
      },
      "selection": {
        "y_scroll_2": {"type": "interval", "bind": "scales", "encodings": ["y"]},
        "x_scroll": {"type": "interval", "bind": "scales", "encodings": ["x"]}
      }
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {"scale": {"x": "shared", "y": "independent"}}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jake. Indeed, plots have now a linked horinzal axis.
But is there a way now to zoom freely on vertical axis of each plot ?
In fact I would like to display linked horizontal axis but free vertical axis.

Comment: Very close. I am learning Vega-lite in fact.
Very close because is there a way to zoom only on specific axis when mouse over it ?

Comment: Yes there is. You should start a new post for new questions.