# How to zoom only on a specific axis when mouse over it?

Tags: vega-lite

Starting from this [concrete example](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVJOmNlADWESlAjEQAXyXEocqGrQBtUAHcay%20mjEABkClTG0kWQgAMzZtBA9QKJpBTDhtfVVMBgRKCABPBCY2QQBeMoByAEkAIQBZcvsAXSVkbTN9YVk4RRA4WWdlGlkyNFAAD1GQJLhBZQy1btC8nG70VIQcWKQ9BxA8yenZ-RxtGihFkExl1ZAARwYIzDo1GlJ7XYgZuCgnuUm8gD60G0xUEAIAjJMrit9ENUtpiNsekwhnN0NBtnAID0%20gMhmRsah3HsQI1dmMgVAQYI9JpLtdYbJ4Yi9EoUbI0SAMYIsTj%20mxBsNCcSJmS7A5QGEItFYvEiYlkvD5lkcvlCsUyiVygBxADyuu1DTszRArXa6E6F1xAvxkwmdMOnMyF2hN3Wm3COyU%20wdNBmnJOZxdDPQ90ezyeb3FSk%20PJ%207HkdMBwNBAIATFCQyA4WkWcjUfpubylNbBQSPCSyUoKSmaZmYegcwikWyC%20jXDzsSX%20WXhSBReLjUptFjim86UW7YWYEgR3NvYzlHAVhy%20ph3nYgA) where 2 plots are linked on their horizontal axis and free on their vertical axis, is there a way to zoom only on a specific axis when the mouse is over it ?

The zoom actually set is common to both axis.

Answer (score 0):

If you want scrolling to be independent in each panel, you need to do two things:

- set `resolve.scale.x` and `resolve.scale.y` to `"independent"`, so the scales will not be linked.
- use a different name for the bound selection in each panel, so the selectors will not be linked.

For example ([vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVJOmNlADWESlAjEQAXyXEocqGrQBtUJm1JZEAGZs2ggeoP40gphw2vqqmAwIlBAAnghMbIIAvNkA5ACSAEIAsjn2ALpKyNpm+sKycIogcLLOyjSyZGigAB5dIOFwgsqxag1KmMk4DehRCDhBSHoOIMl9A0P6ONo0UGMgE1P6AI4Mvph0ajSk9ssQg3BQ53J90NoZggD6AIx9B9Mg7Si2mIi0aTHaw3Q0EWcAgNwcXh8fkCwVC-QiQJG8USKTSGWymRyAHEAPIkomlOwVEBVGroOp7ZqtdqdTQgXps9aQgxRRp-fSzeY+JZKVacmiDblbHZ7fnoE5nC7na52W73R7seRs17vD4AJl+k3+gOiIL0SnBsm50MEsPh1O0sIy121rltfQ5AKtcCm3tkmEaYq9yh9zRD-vhQA)):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/stocks.csv"},
  "vconcat": [
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.symbol==='IBM'"}],
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
      },
      "selection": {"scroll_1": {"type": "interval", "bind": "scales"}}
    },
    {
      "transform": [{"filter": "datum.symbol==='GOOG'"}],
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
      },
      "selection": {"scroll_2": {"type": "interval", "bind": "scales"}}
    }
  ],
  "resolve": {"scale": {"x": "independent", "y": "independent"}}
}
```

Comment: I have been missunderstood. I would like both plots linked by their horizontal axis and free on their vertical axis. But also have a zoom behaviout that allows zooming on a specific axis. Not on the whole plot.

Comment: Can you point to an example somewhere of the behavior that you want to replicate? Does the first answer of https://stackoverflow.com/a/62460026/2937831 not address your question?

Comment: Here are the behaviour that I am looking for:
https://demo.bokeh.org/stocks

Comment: - when mouse is over the plot, zoom occurs on both axis
- when mouse is over a axis (horizontal or vertical), zoom occurs on this specific axis.

In the Bokeh Stocks example, time series plots have a linked horizontal axis.

Comment: There is no way in Vega-lite to have different zooming behaviors for different parts of the same sub chart.

Comment: Ok too bad. In fact I would like this specific behaviour for my project.